# Where does software and trade-journal expenses go on Schedule C?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, schedule-c

I can't seem to find on which line of schedule C the following expenses go:

- Trade Journal
- Software*

*Some of the software has pay-as-you-go, monthly-fee type billing.

Comment: Check out Part V, it is the catch-all for expenses that do not fit the pre-defined buckets in earlier sections.